# Can we save smtp configuration in db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp

Can we store smtp settings in db and fetch them and use in environments/*.rb file to use the smtp in run time ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In a regular way it is not possible, because environment/*.rb is loaded at application startup, and you can't change it in runtime.

You can use some mailing gem, that can be configured in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-with-dynamic-delivery-options

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def welcome_email(user, company)
    @user = user
    @url  = user_url(@user)
    delivery_options = { user_name: company.smtp_user,
                     password: company.smtp_password,
                     address: company.smtp_host }
    mail(to: @user.email,
        subject: "Please see the Terms and Conditions attached",
        delivery_method_options: delivery_options)
  end
end
```